# Avoid displaying of previous pages after logout ASP.NET C# 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, logout

I am having problem with logout. After Logging out of the application also, when a user presses browser back button those secured pages are displaying.

And also the page load event is not firing for browser back button. I am using master page
and content page.

My logout functionality is in master page.

```
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Here my login page is Default.aspx.

Comment: clear browser cache after logout

Comment: clearing browser cache will achieve this but is shows document no longer available " browser message " . I want like if user presses back button he should stay in login page only after logout. I am not using ASP.NET membership provider

Comment: Even StackOverflow is having this Issue.

Comment: you may check the session for credentials on page load event of each page if exist then continue or else redirect to login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is, just don't cache the page that you want to prevent user from access after you logs out:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not redirect to `Default.aspx`, in my way, I usually create a "middle page", this page will check sessions and and prevent go back previous page after logout.

The route could be like this:
logout -> clear session page -> login page

So, from login page, if you click back button on browser, it would let you to clear session page and go back login area.

Comment: Seems like good idea. Can u paste code u  used for this

Comment: I just upload a sample, you can get it and try it [Sample](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3JuSwxrF5UlMnJmYWJKRllRZTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: am not able to get sample

Comment: can you try this [file](http://www.mediafire.com/?zakvx7njnade2v7)